# Get multiple file contents to one Ansible variable

Tags: ansible, ubuntu-18.04, cat

On Ubuntu 18 server in directory */home/adminuser/keys* are 5 files that contain key parts:

```
/home/adminuser/key/
|-  unseal_key_0
|-  unseal_key_1
|-  unseal_key_2
|-  unseal_key_3
|-  unseal_key_4
```

File contents:

```
1bbeaafab5037a287bde3e5203c8b2cd205f4cc55b4fcffe7931658dc20d8cdcdf
bdf7a6ee4c493aca5b9cc2105077ec67738a0e8bf21936abfc5d1ff8080b628fcb
545c087d3d59d02556bdbf8690c8cc9faafec0e9766bb42de3a7884159356e91b8
053207b0683a8a2886129f7a1988601629a9e7e0d8ddbca02333ce08f1cc7b3887
2320f6275804341ebe5d39a623dd309f233e454b4453c692233ca86212a3d40b5f
```

Part of Ansible playbook (task):

```yaml
- name: Reading file contents
      command: cat {{item}}
      register: unseal_keys
      with_fileglob: "/home/adminuser/keys/*"
```

The error that I get:

> "[WARNING]: Unable to find '/home/adminuser/keys' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)"

I have tried to:

- change user that creates directory and files
- change path to /home/adminuser/keys/ and /home/adminuser/keys

I expect all of the file contents (that is parts of a single key) to be merged into one string:

```
1bbeaafab5037a287bde3e5203c8b2cd205f4cc55b4fcffe7931658dc20d8cdcdfbdf7a6ee4c493aca5b9cc2105077ec67738a0e8bf21936abfc5d1ff8080b628fcb545c087d3d59d02556bdbf8690c8cc9faafec0e9766bb42de3a7884159356e91b8 053207b0683a8a2886129f7a1988601629a9e7e0d8ddbca02333ce08f1cc7b38872320f6275804341ebe5d39a623dd309f233e454b4453c692233ca86212a3d40b5f
```

Comment: Could you reformat code so that is formatted correctly (`code`)? On the topic itself: I would say that you should check which host is targeted: maybe you address certain hosts, but your intention is to merge files on the localhost (`delegate_to: localhost`)

Comment: If you are already using `cat`, which according man page "_concatenate files and print on the standard output_", you can simply use `shell: cat /home/adminuser/keys/unseal_keys_* | tr -d '\n'` or `unseal_keys_{0,1,2,3,4}` or `unseal_keys_{0..4}`, etc.

Comment: You're asking for `with_fileglob: "/home/adminuser/keys/*"`, but at the beginning of your question you show us `/home/adminuser/key/`. Note the difference between  `key` and `keys`.

Answer (score 1):

Given the files below for testing

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/admin/
/tmp/admin/
└── key
    ├── key_0
    ├── key_1
    └── key_2

1 directory, 3 files
```

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/admin/key/key_0
abc
```

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/admin/key/key_1
def
```

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/admin/key/key_2
ghi
```

---

Use the module [*assemble*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assemble_module.html#ansible-builtin-assemble-module-assemble-configuration-files-from-fragments) to: *"assemble a configuration file from fragments."*

Declare the path

```yaml
  key_all_path: /tmp/admin/key_all
```

and *assemble* the fragments

```yaml
    - assemble:
        src: /tmp/admin/key
        dest: "{{ key_all_path }}"
```

This will create the file */tmp/admin/key_all*

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/admin/key_all 
abc
def
ghi
```

Read the file and *join* the lines. Declare the variable

```yaml
  key_all: "{{ lookup('file', key_all_path).splitlines()|join('') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  key_all: abcdefghi
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    key_all_path: /tmp/admin/key_all
    key_all: "{{ lookup('file', key_all_path).splitlines()|join('') }}"

  tasks:

    - assemble:
        src: /tmp/admin/key
        dest: "{{ key_all_path }}"

    - debug:
        var: key_all
```

Comment: Just learned something new since I am was not aware of the `assemble` module for the case where "_... does not support a `conf.d` style structure where it is easy to build up the configuration from multiple sources. `assemble` will take a directory of files that can be local or have already been transferred to the system, and concatenate them together to produce a destination file._"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks !
Problem was in paths and hosts where task had to be executed.
Problem is solved by locating and reading files localy and executing this task:

```
- name: Reading file contents
  command: cat "{{item}}"
  register: keys                       ----> all file contents to variable "keys"
  with_fileglob: "~/keys/*"            ----> this is path to directory all files are storedon my local machine
   delegate_to: localhost              ----> here I specify that this task will be executed on local machine
  become: false                        ----> remove sudo so that password is not requested
```

Comment: Just a note, since you are [Iterating over a simple list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-a-simple-list) for performance reason and resource consumption "_You can pass a list directly to a parameter for some plugins. Most of the packaging modules, like `yum` and `apt,` have this capability. When available, passing the list to a parameter is better than looping over the task._". This is true for the `command` and `shell` module too. So in your case it would be `cat ~/keys/*`.